# Wordpress Redirect Snafu - Cannot login into wp-admin console

Tags: wordpress

Well, I'm in a pickle.

This morning, I planned to complete a site redirect from my [Wordpress location](http://www.engineerapplication.com) to my [Strikingly](http://www.enginapp.com) site. So, my approach to doing so was to execute a "Change URL" action on my Wordpress domain (from engineerapplication.com to enginapp.com).

Well, after I did this, I now am unable to log in to my wp-admin location on my Wordpress site, and the page is in shambles. And no, I didn't do a backup because I'm an idiot. :)

Is there any way I can backdoor my way into my "domain".com/wp-admin site and clean things up there?

(Note: this will just be a temporary fix until the site owner can do a redirect on his servers. I just want to make sure there's no lag in quality.)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are talking about, excuse me if I've misunderstood. I've had little issues like this quite a few times. Easiest way is to follow [these instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database) for changing the URL directly in the database.

You can get into phpMyAdmin for the right database, go to wp_options, look for the siteurl and the home fields, and change them back. Then get into your Wordpress Admin, make the right backups, and then switch things over properly and only change the URL on the new site.

Good luck.